# Is is possible to proxy a COM interface using Spring.Net?

Tags: c#, com, spring.net, dynamic-proxy

I am trying to create a dynamic proxy using Spring.NET and C# for a COM interface.  I am currently experimenting using code, not config files.
I have code similar to the following:

```
Type comInterfaceType = typeof(ICOMInterface);
ProxyFactory proxyFactory = new ProxyFactory();
proxyFactory.AddInterface(comInterfaceType);
proxyFactory.GetProxy();
```

It blows up at the GetProxy() call with the following exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The property with name ArraySubType can't be found 
    in the type System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute, but is present as 
    a named property on the attributeData 
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(
    (System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType)28, ArraySubType = 0, SizeParamIndex
    = 0, SizeConst = 0, IidParameterIndex = 0, SafeArraySubType = 0)]
```

Is this simply not possible?  I am still using Spring.NET 1.1, is this possible in the newer versions (which we will finally be moving to soon)?

UPDATE: After experimenting, I got this same error with slightly different parameters (ie. UnmanagedType 44) when proxying the Form class as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this was a result of a bug in Spring.NET 1.1 when generating attributes for proxied methods: https://issues.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET-852?page=com.atlassian.streams.streams-jira-plugin%3Aactivity-stream-issue-tab.  We have a solution to test migrating to the latest Spring version, and so I tested this there.  It worked.